# Using loops to create copies and rename files

Tags: python, loops

python noob here and stumped.  I am trying to copy files from a source dir to output dir, rename files and loop all of this over again for each member in groups.

my output so far only gives me only the first set of files for john in groups.

can someone point out what i'm doing wrong??  Please help..

```
import os
import shutil
from glob import glob
import easygui as eg

groups = {'mark': ('john', 'lisa', 'craig', 'jessie'),}

title = 'Title'
msg = 'Choose Input Directory'
default = 'C\\:'
inputdir = eg.diropenbox(msg, title, default)

files = glob(inputdir + '/*.*')

x = input('How many copies?   ')
y = raw_input('Text for filename?   ')

otitle = 'Title'
omsg = 'Choose Output Directory'
odefault = 'C\\:'
outputdir = eg.diropenbox(omsg, otitle, odefault)

x = x - 1
z = 0

for members in groups['mark']:
    while x >= 0:
        for filename in files:
            shutil.copy(filename, outputdir)
        ofiles = glob(outputdir + '/*.*')
        for ofilename in ofiles:
            if '-' and 'Template' in ofilename:
                os.rename(ofilename, ofilename.replace('-', str(x)).replace('Template', y))
        x -= 1

    files = glob(outputdir + '/*.*')
    for filename in files:
        if 'person' in filename:
            os.rename(filename, filename.replace('person', groups['mark'][z]))
    z += 1
```

Comment: why you use `groups['mark'][z]` and not just `members`?

Comment: I actually just realized that after I posted haha, i am a total noob, go easy on me...  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after the first iteration, `x` is already `0`, so you don't enter the `while` loop .

I think you want to store the number of copies and reset `x` to it after each iteration.

something like:

```
copies = input('How many copies?   ')

 ...    
x = copies - 1

for members in groups['mark']:
    x = copies - 1        
    while x >= 0:
       ...
```

Comment: I think you are wrong, your `while` iteration continue as long as `x >= 0`, which means that it stops and go to next member only when `x < 0`. just try this.

Comment: i got an error for line 30 (shutil.copy(filename, outputdir))...  it says "Error: 'path/filename' and 'path/filename' are the same file"... I might have just figured out why i got the error :)